# Twitter - get user details after tweet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter

I have added a twitter share button in my site.

The following code is executed when the user tweets -

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet' , function(event) {
  // do something here     
});
```

But i want the details of the user who tweeted, the user name / user email (response) from twitter which i have to store it in my database.

Is there any way to get these details from twitter share?
Any help would be appreciated.